# What is the Galois group $\text{Gal}\big(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},\omega)\big)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive $4$th root of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

What is the Galois group $\text{Gal}\big(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},\omega)\big)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive $4$th root of unity?

What I concluded was:

We know that this group has order $8$, once $x^4 - 2$ is te minimum polynomial of $\sqrt[4]{2}$ and $\omega$ has a minimum polynomial with degree $2$, once $2 = \phi(4) = 2^2 - 2 = 2.$
Ok, how do I identify who is this group?

I know that is enough to determine the homomorphisms evaluated on $\sqrt[4]{2}$ and $\omega$.

Then:

$$\phi(\sqrt[4]{2}) = \sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[4]{2}i,-\sqrt[4]{2},-i\sqrt[4]{2}$$
$$\tau(i) = i, -i.$$

So, whats next?

Comment: A well-known primitive 4th root of unity would be $i$. And that makes $\omega^2=-1$ not a possible image of $\omega$

Comment: because $-1$ is not a zero of $f(x) = x^4 - 2?$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Can I conclude that this Galois group is isomorphic to $Z_4\times Z_2$?

Comment: $Q(\sqrt^{1/4}(2))$ is  a the splitting field of $x^4-2$ and $\sqrt^{1/4}(2)$ is a primitive root of this field, the Galois group acts transitively on primitive roots that you can determine to compute this group

Comment: @TsemoAristide $Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$ is not the splitting field of $x^4 - 2$.

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi note that $\tau\phi= \phi^{-1}\tau$